# Rationality of the Gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, rationality-testing

I am wondering whether it is correct to say, or whether there is a way to prove that, when $a$ is a positive rational number but not an integer, the [complete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) of $a$, namely $\Gamma(a)$, is always irrational.

In general, I am not sure how to approach a problem involving the rationality of a number if it is defined by integrals.

Comment: Read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function Note that in many cases the number $\;\pi\;$ plays a central role.

Comment: Thank you. That's why I have the conjecture that they should be irrational in general.

Comment: @We ...and unless you can prove something specific for **any** rational non integer argument for $\;\Gamma\;$, and that doesn't look very easy to achieve, it will remain that: a mere conjecture.

Comment: Hmm... I wanted to ask what research has been done on this (or what are some possible ways to approach the problem) but I think that question would be too broad and off topic for this site.